# Joomla template resize module position

Tags: php, html, css, templates, joomla

I'm using chimera template by rockettheme.
Linke: http://www.rockettheme.com/docs/joomla/templates/chimera/positions.md

I need to reduce the height of the "topfullwidth"-module-position (somewhere in the template-file, no option in settings).

I searched the index.php file for 'topfullwidth' but all I found was the following:

```
<?php /** Begin TopFullWidth **/ if ($gantry->countModules('topfullwidth')) : ?>
<div id="rt-topfullwidth">
    <?php echo $gantry->displayModules('topfullwidth','basic','standard'); ?>
    <div class="clear">
    </div>
</div>
<?php /** End TopFullWidth **/ endif; ?>
```

Where is the size set so I can change its value? I think I should look for it in a css-file, but there are quite a lot of different ones and I can't find "topfullwidth" in any of the files in the css folder of the template.

Comment: @MirkoMikan thank you for your reply, I found a solution and answered my question if anyone else has a similar problem

Answer (score 0):

I figured out an answer: in your template-folder there is a css-folder, in which you have to create a file named *template-name*_custom.css In this css you can define own styles.